"Duplicate -rpath '@executable_path' ignored" warning after updating to Xcode 16
After upgrading to Xcode 16, I got the warning Duplicate -rpath '@executable_path' ignored. The warning disappears when I clean the project and delete the derived data. Even after I built it, there is still no warning. But the warning reappears when I activate the previews or run it on a simulator. But the warning doesn't appear when I build/run with a real device or Any iOS Device (arm64).
I think something is wrong with the preview or simulator, but I couldn't find anything. I researched everywhere, but I didn't find this warning anywhere. Did no one come across this warning?
Now I'm stuck with this annoying warning. And my preview was crashing a lot. Maybe this is the reason.
Here is the full warning:
cd /Users/username/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com\~apple\~CloudDocs/Xcode/MyApp
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/
codeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -Xlinker -reproducible -target x86_64-apple-ios15.0-simulator -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator18.0.sdk -O0 -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gqyiajecvjcgeobbbdpliosrshwu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gqyiajecvjcgeobbbdpliosrshwu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PackageFrameworks -F/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gqyiajecvjcgeobbbdpliosrshwu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PackageFrameworks -F/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gqyiajecvjcgeobbbdpliosrshwu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gqyiajecvjcgeobbbdpliosrshwu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PackageFrameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fsanitize\=thread -Xlinker -debug_variant -e ___debug_blank_executor_main -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __debug_dylib -Xlinker /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gqyiajecvjcgeobbbdpliosrshwu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/MyApp-DebugDylibPath-normal-x86_64.txt -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __debug_instlnm -Xlinker /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gqyiajecvjcgeobbbdpliosrshwu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/MyApp-DebugDylibInstallName-normal-x86_64.txt -Xlinker -filelist -Xlinker /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gqyiajecvjcgeobbbdpliosrshwu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/MyApp-ExecutorLinkFileList-normal-x86_64.txt -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gqyiajecvjcgeobbbdpliosrshwu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/MyApp.app-Simulated.xcent -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __ents_der -Xlinker /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gqyiajecvjcgeobbbdpliosrshwu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/MyApp.app-Simulated.xcent.der /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gqyiajecvjcgeobbbdpliosrshwu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp.debug.dylib -o /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gqyiajecvjcgeobbbdpliosrshwu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp

This is the inline version so you can see it more easily:
Ld /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gqyiajecvjcgeobbbdpliosrshwu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp normal (in target 'MyApp' from project 'MyApp')
cd /Users/username/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com\~apple\~CloudDocs/Xcode/MyApp
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/
codeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -Xlinker -reproducible -target x86_64-apple-ios15.0-simulator 
-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/
iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator18.0.sdk -O0 -L/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gqyiajecvjcgeobbbdpliosrshwu
/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gqyiajecvjcgeobbbdpliosrshwu
/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PackageFrameworks -F/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gqyiajecvjcgeobbbdpliosrshwu
/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PackageFrameworks -F/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gqyiajecvjcgeobbbdpliosrshwu
/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path
 -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gqyiajecvjcgeobbbdpliosrshwu
/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PackageFrameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path
/Frameworks -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker
 -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fsanitize\=thread -Xlinker -debug_variant -e 
___debug_blank_executor_main -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker
 __debug_dylib -Xlinker /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gqyiajecvjcgeobbbdpliosrshwu
/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/MyApp-DebugDylibPath-normal-x86_64.txt
 -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __debug_instlnm -Xlinker 
/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gqyiajecvjcgeobbbdpliosrshwu
/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/MyApp-DebugDylibInstallName-normal-x86_64.txt
 -Xlinker -file list -Xlinker /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gqyiajecvjcgeobbbdpliosrshwu
/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/MyApp-ExecutorLinkFileList-normal-x86_64.txt
 -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gqyiajecvjcgeobbbdpliosrshwu
/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/MyApp.app-Simulated.xcent -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT 
-Xlinker __ents_der -Xlinker /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gqyiajecvjcgeobbbdpliosrshwu
/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/MyApp.app-Simulated.xcent.der /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gqyiajecvjcgeobbbdpliosrshwu
/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp.debug.dylib -o /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gqyiajecvjcgeobbbdpliosrshwu
/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp

I saw that the cd command had 2 @executable_path as the warning says, of course. I tried to delete the derived data, but it didn't work. I tried to delete the Previews folder, but it didn't work. I tried to delete the entire Xcode library folder, but it didn't work, again. Now, I don't know how to fix it.
Environment:

Xcode 16.1
MacOS 15.1.1

Project:

Has SwiftLint and SwiftFormat via homebrew.
Is an iOS 15 app.
Has package dependencies via SwiftPM.
Has been recently migrated from cocoapods.
Runpath Search Paths parameter is empty.


I also have similar issue, and the warning disappears after successful build. I know it is not a solution, but I would ignore this warning because it seems to be an error in Xcode.
